# DBeaver SSL is disabled

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, dbeaver

I am trying to access elasticsearch instance through DBeaver, and getting the error SSL is disabled when trying to access the connection string.

[image: screenshot of the error]

**the connection properties**

[image: connection properties]

**interestingly, the SSL tab / option is NOT even displayed in the connection properties:**

[image]

It seems like the SSL is disabled as a global setting within DBeaver, but I have not been able to locate the same or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome this by specifying the details in Driver properties. Just choose "Edit Driver Setting" under "Connection Settings".
Go to "Driver Properties" add the keys and values according to your needs.
In my case I specified trust-store username and password
[image]